# ImportError: `iplot` can only run inside an IPython Notebook

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython, chainer

When I run the following code in PyCharm on a Mac：

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))


import time
import copy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import chainer
import chainer.functions as F
import chainer.links as L
from plotly import tools
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, iplot_mpl
init_notebook_mode()
data = pd.read_csv('../input/Data/Stocks/goog.us.txt')
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data = data.set_index('Date')
print(data.index.min(), data.index.max())
data.head()
```

There were some errors:

```
UserWarning: Accelerate has been detected as a NumPy backend library.
vecLib, which is a part of Accelerate, is known not to work correctly with Chainer.
We recommend using other BLAS libraries such as OpenBLAS.
For details of the issue, please see
https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tips.html#mnist-example-does-not-converge-in-cpu-mode-on-mac-os-x.

Please be aware that Mac OS X is not an officially supported OS.

  ''')  # NOQA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yindeyong/Desktop/PythonProjects/pythonstock/DQNStcok.py", line 33, in <module>
    init_notebook_mode()
  File "/Users/yindeyong/Desktop/PythonProjects/envs/stockenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/offline/offline.py", line 250, in init_notebook_mode
    raise ImportError('`iplot` can only run inside an IPython Notebook.')
ImportError: `iplot` can only run inside an IPython Notebook.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm new in Chainer and DQN. Could anyone help me edit this code to make it work? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know exactly about your error, but having used PyCharm from soo much time I would just say, check whether chainer and other libs are installed in PyCharm. Because if you have an interpreter in a virtual environment associated with a project and not set to globally on your system, you'll have to first install it from Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Install

Comment: I’m using virtualenv do you think I need use conda?

Comment: This is a question about plotting, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `deep-learnng`, or `openblas` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to run plotly interactive functions (`i` prefix) in a normal Python code (i.e. not IPython Notebook). `iplot` provides an interactive graph with which you can play inside the notebook.

I'd start with removing `iplot` import and replacing it with normal `plot`. Also, remove `iplot_mpl` and `init_notebook_mode` from your imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can install 'ipython' in the virtual environment and then try running it directly from the terminal.

- Activate the virtual environment
- pip3 install ipython
- python3 prog.py

Worked in my case.